# Recommendations for Cedar tree bark damage

Tags: tree-care, damage, cedar, bark

The bark on this cedar tree got nicked by a falling branch. We don’t want to lose this tree, so I’m researching the best course of action. One horticulturalist friend told me to just strip off the remaining damaged bark (trying to preserve as much intact as possible), and the tree will recover nicely with no significant concerns.

Anyone care to share their (preferably educated) opinion?

Here’s a Picture

[image]

Comment: It is a cedar? It appears to have large round leaves.

Answer (score 2):

That advice to "strip off the remaining damaged bark (trying to preserve as much intact as possible), and the tree will recover nicely with no significant concern" is correct.

What will happen is that the tree will grow over the wound and compartmentalize the damage.  If this  is an important tree you could mulch the area and water to encourage new growth

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like the bark has a problem . It would be abnormal for a falling branch to hurt healthy bark. I have deer scrape off 3/4 of bark at a diameter and the trees survive. The deer like to rub antler's on smooth bark trees like holly and magnolia, and any species of young tree.